# How to find a subspace that satisfies a direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

The problem states:

Suppose

$$U=\{(x,x,y,y)\in F^4:x,y\in F\}$$

Find a subspace $W$ of $F^4$ such that $F^4$ equals the direct sum of $U$ and $ W$.

So I know that we are basically trying to find a $W$ such that when added with you there is only one way to write the sum such that it equals $F^4$.

My thoughts:

My best guess is that $W = \{(0,0,0,0)\}$ because that way your sum is unique. For example, if you get $U = (1, 1, 1, 1)$ the only possible way to obtain this value with the addition of these sets is by doing $(1+0, 1+0, 1+0, 1+0)$ which ends up being $(1, 1, 1, 1)$. If you were to make a change to any of the $x$'s or $y$'s from $U$, it is impossible to obtain the same result from a different way. Can anyone corroborate if I'm going in the right direction?

Comment: You want $U\oplus W = F^4 = \{(w, x, y, z)\in F^4: w, x, y, z\in F\}$

Answer (score 1):

What we are basically trying to find is a space $W$ such that every $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in F^4$ can be written as $w+(x,x,y,y)$ with $w\in W$ and $(x,x,y,y)\in U$.  This can be done for example if $W=\{(u,0,v,0):u,v\in F\}$.

Your suggestion that $W=\{(0,0,0,0)\}$ isn't going to work, because if you add $(0,0,0,0)$ to an element of $U$, that element still has the form $(x,x,y,y)$. You thus won't be able to get through that addition vectors in $F^4$ which don't have that form, say $(0,1,0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you are supposed to do now.

Answer (score 1):

Put
\begin{align*}
u_1 &= \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} &
u_2 &= \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
and note that $\{u_1,u_2\}$ is a basis for $U$.

> If $\{u_1,u_2,v,w\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb F^4$, then $\Bbb F^4=U\oplus\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{v,w\}$

Can you prove this boxed statement?

Now, we can find suitable $v$ and $w$ algorithmically by computing the reduced row-echelon form of the matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|rrrr}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Row-reducing gives $\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}$
$$
\rref
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]
$$
The second two pivot columns in the reduced row-echelon form correspond to our desired $v$ and $w$ in the original matrix. That is, choosing
\begin{align*}
v &= \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} &
w &= \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
allows us to write $\Bbb F^4=U\oplus\Span\{v,w\}$.